# Deleting row if there is another row with same value in column A and that row has value in c

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, row

I'm trying to write a macro that does the following:

1. it takes the value of column A - row per row (from down to up) = initial row
2. it checks if there is another row with the same value in column A
3. if yes: it takes the first match
4. it checks if the matched row has something written in column C
5. if yes: it deletes the initial row

I have the following but it doesn't work and now it seems that there is also the error "unable to get the Match property of the worksheetfunction class.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Testing()

Dim x               As Long
Dim y               As Long
Dim LastRow         As Long
Dim MatchedRow      As Long
Dim RowValue        As String

LastRow = Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Row

For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1

RowValue = Range("A" & x).Value

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & x), Range("A" & x).Text) > 1 Then
    MatchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RowValue, Range("A1:A" & x), 0)
    If Range("C" & MatchedRow).Value <> "" Then
        Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End If

Next x

End Sub
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3):

The error is occurring because `RowValue` is declared as a string. If column A has numbers the `MATCH` function returns an error (unless the numbers are formatted as text).

Change `Dim RowValue        As String` to `Dim RowValue        As Variant` and it will work with all data types

Comment: Nice. Thought this would only solve the match error, but it seems that the whole code works as intended now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an answer posted above but on a related note, you could tighten up your code by changing that [WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) to a [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(1), Range("A" & x).Text, Columns(3), Chr(42)) > 1 Then
    Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```